# Get the next 10 values of the SEQUENCE at once

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

I want to get the next 10 values of the SEQUENCE at once.

I can get those individually by calling

```sql
SELECT setval('myseq', ...);           -- Next nextval will return 43
```

10 times back to back.

On Microsoft SQL server, I can do something like below to get all the 10 at once.

```sql
DECLARE
    @range_first_value  SQL_VARIANT
  , @range_last_value   SQL_VARIANT
  , @range_cycle_count  INT
  , @sequence_increment SQL_VARIANT
  , @sequence_min_value SQL_VARIANT
  , @sequence_max_value SQL_VARIANT;
EXEC sys.sp_sequence_get_range
    @sequence_name = N''                                -- nvarchar(776)
  , @range_size = 0                                     -- bigint
  , @range_first_value = @range_first_value OUTPUT      -- sql_variant
  , @range_last_value = @range_last_value OUTPUT        -- sql_variant
  , @range_cycle_count = @range_cycle_count OUTPUT      -- int
  , @sequence_increment = @sequence_increment OUTPUT    -- sql_variant
  , @sequence_min_value = @sequence_min_value OUTPUT    -- sql_variant
  , @sequence_max_value = @sequence_max_value OUTPUT    -- sql_variant
```

Is there an equivalent on PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why do you need these values? You can also get them after the INSERT (or UPDATE) on a table, using RETURNING.

Comment: Apparently some requirement to reserving them first, associate other elements in the application memory and write the whole thing to the database as once. If write fails discard all including those in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html).

```sql
select nextval('myseq')
from generate_series(1, 10);
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/-SlLRhsE)

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to get the next ten sequence values is to call `nextval()` ten times, like klin's answer suggests.

For that to be efficient, you should define the sequence with a `CACHE` value of 10 or more, like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq CACHE 15;
```

With a definition like that, the first `nextval()` call will fetch 15 value from the sequence, return the first one and cache the rest in the database session. The next 14 `nextval()` calls will use these cached values and don't actually have to access the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an array of int/bigint as necessary:

```
select array_agg( nextval('myseq') )
  from generate_series(1, 10);
```